# Apache AliasMatch - How to Specify Multiple Hosts?

Tags: apache

In my httpd.conf I have an AliasMatch rule that I need applied to all VirtualHosts **except for one**. Is there an elegant way to avoid copying the rule into each VirtualHost directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. If there's other stuff that belongs in all the vhosts but one, though, you could put those directives all in one file, then [`Include`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#include) that file in each vhost that needs it.